# How to deserialize Object with superclass children?

Tags: c#, json.net, unreal-engine4

I'm working on an extension for https://github.com/13xforever/gvas-converter with the ability to parse UnrealEngine .sav files. (https://github.com/RagingLightning/gvas-converter/blob/master/GvasFormat/Gvas.cs)

I have three relevant classes:

`public class Gvas`: main class to be deserialized, has a field `public List<UEProperty> Properties = new List<UEProperty>();`

`public abstract class UEProperty`: base class for all possible Unreal Engine properties
with a field `string Type` denoting which subclass the current one is

`public class UEStringProperty : UEProperty`: fully functional class extending `UEProperty` tailored to the String variant

When I deserialize the `Gvas` object lie this:

```
Gvas data = JsonConverter.DeserialiteObject<Gvas>(<json-string>);
```

the deserializer tries to instantiate the `UEProperty` class multiple times to populate the `Properties` list and fails, since the class is abstract.

How can I tell the deserializer to instantiate a subclass based on th value of `Type` (eg. instantiate `UEStringProperty` when `Type == "StringProperty"`)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on the default behavior of JsonConverter.DeserializeObject(), you may have to use a Custom JsonSerializer and a custom SerializationBinder instead of the DefaultSerializationBinder to get more control over the deserialization.

JsonSerializer offers more control than JsonConverter. For full control, you can derive a class from it and override methods.

The reason you have to do this is because, basic JSON serialization doesn't have enough type fidelity to round-trip back to your custom types. JSON just has the basics such as objects, properties, arrays, strings, numbers etc.,

**See this article for details.**

https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/create-a-custom-json-serialization-binder-to-resolve-derived-types-ON

*Article excerpt:*

> Serialization and deserialization of derived types is unfortunately
> not straightforward regardless of the serializer you use. A solution
> to resolve derived types correctly for JsonSerializer is to use
> TypeNameHandling and add a custom JSON serialization Binder that
> derives from the DefaultSerializationBinder to override the BindToName
> and BindToType.